# How can I pass a List<T> from a View to a Controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

If my Model has a property `List<MyType> MyProperty` (where MyType is a complex type), how can I pass this to a Controller Action?

e.g.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult UpdateAll(List<MyType> thingy)
```

If I just use

```
Model.MyProperty
```

It turns up in the controller as `null`

I can't bend my mind round the examples I can find - but what I can pick up leads me to think I should state that my view is NOT based on an `IEnumerable<MyType>` (nor can/should it be).

EDIT: what I want to do with it is

```
 <a id="updateall" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" href="@Url.Action("UpdateAll", "MyController", new { area = "Operator", myproperty=Model.MyProperty})"><span class="ui-button-text">Update All</span></a>
```

EDIT2: Is it as simple as that I need to serialize it before passing it? But I'd have thought that would have very quickly come up as an answer/search result...

Comment: Can you please post your view code? Are you sure about `HttpGet`? If you post your form use `HttpPost`

Comment: yes - very possibly it should be Post - that's part of what I don't know...

Comment: Ah yes, I started with HttpPost but got "Server Error in '/' Application.
The resource cannot be found. "

Comment: Then its a problem with route. Check the action name and controller name used in form action

Comment: it routes fine when annotated HttpGet...

Comment: You are sending a  parameter as a query string in url and it is a link. `HttpGet` is correct. But the property name `MyProperty=Model.MyProperty` in a link should same as your model property name. `Ex: Name=Model.Name`. So the modelbinder will check the query string and prepare the model for you based on the parameter name..

Comment: okay. Yes I am using the property name (I'm a tad confused as to what else I could possibly be using...)

Answer (score 2):

Lists are treated a little bit differently in MVC, in order to post data back from a list you need to first render the UI for each item in that list i.e.

```
@model MyComplexModel

@foreach (MyType item in Model.MyProperty)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(x => item.SomeProperty)
    @Html.EditorFor(x => item.AnotherProperty)
}
```

Using the `*For` helpers will generate the appropriate HTML which allows the model binder to know which items in the list it is updating. If you inspect the DOM you should find the HTML for your list items looks something like

```
<input type="text" name="Model.MyProperty[0].SomeProperty" />
<input type="text" name="Model.MyProperty[0].AnotherProperty" />
<input type="text" name="Model.MyProperty[1].SomeProperty" />
<input type="text" name="Model.MyProperty[1].AnotherProperty" />
...
```

Comment: I'm a bit lost as to the theory on all this, sorry. The rendering is a bit more complex, but it is already there ...  foreach (var item in Model.MyProperty) { <td>@Html.TextboxFor(m => item.data.Amount)</td> etc.

Comment: @kpollock if the rendering is already there it should work. You will need to post some actual code for me to inspect further.

Comment: Presumably, it needs to render first because we need it to enumerate the list. That I understand. How to pass it is the tricky part (for me).

Comment: @kpollock you can't pass complex list data to your controller like you are trying to, it needs to be posted. If you don't need an actual UI for it you can render the data in the view using `@Html.HiddenFor`.

Comment: Okay, getting somewhere now. A definitive "you can't pass complex types" helps loads. Fine, makes sense. Everything still must be serialized, I guess - times haven't changed as much as I'd hoped. How DO I pass it then? In response to a button click.

Answer (score 0):

I have the data that is in my View in a javascript object.  In case this is a direction you're going...

I have a `toDictionary` method...

```
(function ($) {
    $.extend({
        toDictionary: function (data, prefix, includeNulls) {
            /// <summary>Flattens an arbitrary JSON object to a dictionary that Asp.net MVC default model binder understands.</summary>
            /// <param name="data" type="Object">Can either be a JSON object or a function that returns one.</data>
            /// <param name="prefix" type="String" Optional="true">Provide this parameter when you want the output names to be prefixed by something (ie. when flattening simple values).</param>
            /// <param name="includeNulls" type="Boolean" Optional="true">Set this to 'true' when you want null valued properties to be included in result (default is 'false').</param>

            // get data first if provided parameter is a function
            data = $.isFunction(data) ? data.call() : data;

            // is second argument "prefix" or "includeNulls"
            if (arguments.length === 2 && typeof (prefix) === "boolean") {
                includeNulls = prefix;
                prefix = "";
            }

            // set "includeNulls" default
            includeNulls = typeof (includeNulls) === "boolean" ? includeNulls : false;
            var result = [];
            _flatten(data, result, prefix || "", includeNulls);

            return result;
        }
    });
}
```

Here is my ajax call where `roles` is a javascript `Object()`:

```
var data = { roleGroups: roles };
$.ajax({
    url: '/Controller/Action',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: $.toDictionary(data)
})
```

And I'm then using a, `IList` on the server...

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult EditRoleGroups(IList<RoleGroupViewModel> roleGroups)
{ 
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: I am not very Ajax or javascript capable - my gut feeling is that surely it's easier than that?

Comment: ... and sadly my stuff is all pure asp.net/mvc/razor [ditto my skills!]